# JTabbed Pane is reading keystrokes and switching tabs

Tags: java, swing, keylistener, jtabbedpane, incompatibility

I'm using a key listener and a jtabbed pane, and whenever I try to use the left and right keys on the keyboard it just switches between the tabs. This is really annoying since I am actually using the arrow keys in one of the tabs. Is there any way to turn off the "switch tab" keystroke thing in java?

Thank you in advance

```
KeyListen keylistener = new KeyListen();
    MainGUI.MainTabbedPane.addKeyListener(keylistener);
    MainGUI.MainTabbedPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "none");
    MainGUI.MainTabbedPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "none");
```

Comment: you shouldn't use keyListeners at all (what is it doing?) Instead, use custom keyBindings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to unregister keybinding, you can make something like this

```
tabComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("LEFT"), "none");
tabComponent.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "none");
```

You may want to take a look at this [How to use KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). It is not recommended to use KeyListeners instead use KeyBindings, cause first you have to have focus and besides keylisteners is for all keys, and keybinding is for specific key.

Comment: So my program still doesn't work here is my code. I'm wondering if you could give me some more insight into why it might not work. (posted code in orginal post) @nachokk

Comment: @nachokk: +1 for update; also consider citing the relevant tutorial section.